# Regular expression for matching 2 numbers (with required decimals) that are separated by at MOST 6 words?

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm looking to construct a regex that matches 2 decimal numbers (MUST contain a decimal point) separated by at most 6 words (words in this case meaning anything that has a space to the left and right to it). The numbers must also be < 1000 and I want to capture the 2 numbers

This is my attempt at a regex but it does not match at all.

```
regex =  /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]+))([^0-9\s] ){1,6}([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]+))\b/i
```

Example:

```
str = 'Min Hourly Rate 33.33 Max Hourly Range: 45.55'
regex.match(str) #returns nil
```

In addition,

```
str = 'Min Hourly Rate 33.33 Max Hourly Range: 45.55 Max Hourly Range: 50.00'
regex.match(str) #should capture 'Min Hourly Rate 33.33 Max Hourly Range: 45.55' (the first match found)
```

Comment: You seem to be stating that the decimal part of the number cannot be followed by a digit or space which is why it's not matching: `(\.[0-9]+))([^0-9\s] )` - whereas it seems like this part of the pattern is trying to define the "words"? e.g. more like `(\.[0-9]+)) ([^0-9\s]+ ){1,6}`

Comment: Doesn't `\b(\d+\.\d+)((?:\s+[^\s\d]+)){0,6}\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)` work? See https://regex101.com/r/RTLYaO/1

Comment: How about [`\b(\d{1,3}\.\d+)(?: +[^\s\d]+){1,6} +(\d{1,3}\.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/0tX3Gl/1)

Comment: Maybe the number match part might be `0*[1-9][0-9]{0,2}\.[0-9]+`. This allows optional leading zeroes. The significant part of the number being a `[1-9]` followed by up to 2 of `[0-9]`. Finally the fractional part.

Comment: If you just want to pull out decimals, then `/\b(\d+\.\d+)\b/` works just fine. The challenge here is that you have a number of other validations and assumptions that need to be met, especially if you're going to apply this to a broader set of data than the limited examples posted. In addition, the use of case-independence in your regex doesn't make sense, as Roman numerals don't have upper- and lowercase versions.

Answer (score 1):

### Analysis

While you *could* do this with a single [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Regexp.html), most likely with the use of a [subexpression call](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Subexpression+Calls), it will be overcomplicated and difficult to debug. You also have a number of other edge cases and conditions to consider, including multivalent validations. Rather than trying to do all of this in a single regular expression, you should divide this up into smaller and more testable steps. While that makes the code longer and (perhaps) visually less elegant, the result is something that can be more easily modified, extended, and tested.

### A More Object-Oriented Approach

Consider the following class, which gives you the right answer with a much simpler regular expression (see the #dynamic_regex_pattern method, which is only about six atoms before interpolation) by delegating some of the other domain logic and validations to specialized methods. It also makes changing your primary regular expression for finding decimals and the maximum distance between them easier to modify because they're constants. On the other hand, the ability to measure the appropriate distance between them becomes more flexible without resorting to subexpressions because the class builds up a dynamic pattern for each specific String.

```rb
# Tested on mainline Ruby 3.2.2. Your
# mileage may vary with other versions.
class ExtractDecimalsFromStrings
  DECIMALS  = /\b(\d+\.\d+)\b/
  MAX_SEP   = 6
  SEP_WORDS = '#{first}\b.*?#{second}\b'

  attr_accessor :str_arr
  attr_reader :results

  def initialize *str
    @results = {}
    @str_arr = str.flatten
  end

  def extract_results
    @str_arr.each do |str|
      decimals = str.scan(DECIMALS).flatten.slice 0, 2
      decimal_error(str) && next unless valid? decimals
      populate_results_from str, decimals
    end
  end

  private

  def decimal_error str
    @results[str] = { error: "not enough decimals to parse" }
  end

  def distance_error str
    @results[str] = { error: "distance exceeds #{MAX_SEP}" }
  end

  def dynamic_regex_pattern decimals
    /#{Regexp.escape decimals.first}\b.*?#{Regexp.escape decimals.last}\b/
  end

  def populate_results_from str, decimals
    pat = dynamic_regex_pattern decimals
    distance = str.match(pat) { within_distance? $& }
    distance ? @results[str]={ first_decimal: decimals[0], second_decimal:
                               decimals[1], distance: distance } :
               distance_error(str)
  end

  def valid? decimals
    decimals.count == 2 && decimals.all? { _1.to_f.ceil.between? 0, 999 }
  end

  def within_distance? match
    words = [match&.to_s.split].flatten.compact
    words.shift && words.pop if words.count >= 2
    words.any? && words.count <= MAX_SEP && words.count
  end
end

example_strings = [
  "Min Hourly Rate 33.33 Max Hourly Range: 45.55",
  "Min Hourly Rate 33.33 Max Hourly Range: 45.55 Max Hourly Range: 50.00",
  "No Rates Specified",
  "33.33 is too far away from as defined by MAX_SEP: 65.00"
]

extractor = ExtractDecimalsFromStrings.new example_strings
extractor.extract_results
pp extractor.results
```

#### Other Points of Interest

Not only will this give you the essential output you wanted, e.g. two decimal numbers within a given distance of each other, but it will also:

1. Provide suitable errors for any String objects that don't contain exactly two decimal values. Any other number of decimals values is treated as an error since the business logic for handling that was undefined.
2. Provides an error message when the distance between two decimals is higher than the maximum permitted.
3. You can use the Hash to identify problem String objects by simply checking the value of the `:error` key when present.
4. It differentiates between different kinds of errors, and you can add your own handlers as needed.
5. It will take any number of String objects as arguments or as an Array.
6. It stores the original String as a Hash key, and the decimal values in sensibly-named sub-keys for easy reference.
7. Since my solution had to calculate distance between decimals anyway, this solution stores the distance between them as an Integer value as bonus info.

Here's the output from the example Array of String above:

```rb
{"Min Hourly Rate 33.33 Max Hourly Range: 45.55"=>
  {:first_decimal=>"33.33", :second_decimal=>"45.55", :distance=>3},
 "Min Hourly Rate 33.33 Max Hourly Range: 45.55 Max Hourly Range: 50.00"=>
  {:first_decimal=>"33.33", :second_decimal=>"45.55", :distance=>3},
 "No Rates Specified"=>{:error=>"not enough decimals to parse"},
 "33.33 is too far away from as defined by MAX_SEP: 65.00"=>{:error=>"distance exceeds 6"}}
```

### Caveats

First and forement, this was done on Ruby 3.2.2. Input and output were tested with reasonable rigor, but no effort was made (or will be made) to make it compatible with other Rubies in the foreseeable future. If it doesn't work on Ruby 2.x, some end-of-life Ruby, or a future version of Ruby with breaking changes to core classes, please feel free to adapt it as needed.

A couple of assumptions were also made about the problem domain. For example, a maximum distance of `6` was taken to mean the number of intervening words, including unseparated punctuation, rather than including the starting and/or ending decimal values. The code is flexible enough to change that as you see fit. See #within_distance? for the implementation details.

In the original question, saying you want to "capture the 2 numbers" was ambiguous, so I chose to interpret that as storing the values in an obvious and retrievable way. If you meant something different, there will likely be other answers that will suit you better.

Neither the original examples nor the posted regex addressed negative values such as `-14.02` or (as you might sometimes see in bookkeeping) `(5.30)`. There are also differences between hyphens, the UTF-8 minus symbol, and so on. Unless you make even more assumptions about the actual character representation of a negative value, it's potentially more complex than you might think. So, I didn't address those out-of-scope issues, although I obviously chose to address others that I thought mattered for this particular question. For anyone who feels strongly about negative values even though it wasn't part of the original question, please feel free to post a different answer. I'm sure someone will find it useful!

The application has a couple of places where the return values are not intrinsically useful. For example, if you call `pp extractor.extract_results` instead of:

```rb
extractor.extract_results
pp extractor.results
```

you will get the return value of the #extract_results method rather than the value of the *@results* Hash via the accessor. Currently, the two are quite different, and while the former does what it says (it extracts stuff) what you actually *want* will be in the Hash after all checks and transformations are done.

These sorts of things are easy to fix, and are probably a good idea to implement in a production application where you want to be able to easily unit test the return value of each separate method, but that was outside the scope of what I was trying to demonstrate here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that:

- a decimal number is the string representation of a non-negative float
- a decimal number's leading digit can only be zero when it is followed immediately by the decimal point
- "word" separators consist of one or more tabs or spaces or combinations thereof
- "anything" in the first sentence means any string that contains one or more characters other than whitespaces and digits

You can match the regular expression

```
rgx = /((?<!\d)(?:\d|[1-9]\d{1,2})\.\d+)(?:[\t ]+[^\s\d]+){0,6}[\t ]+((?<!\d)(?:\d|[1-9]\d{1,2})\.\d+)/
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/QgoWxhVvr4AMf5)

For example,

```
"1.1 abc def 2.2".match(rgx)
  #=> #<MatchData "1.1 abc def 2.2" 1:"1.1" 2:"2.2">
```

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
/
(                 # begin capture group 1
  (?<!\d)         # negative lookbehind asserts preceding char is not a digit
  (?:             # begin non-capture group
    \d            # match digit
    |             # or
    [1-9]         # match a digit other than zero
    \d{1,2}       # match 1 or 2 digits
  )               # end non-capture group    
  \.              # match period
  \d+             # match one or more digits
)                 # end capture group 1
(?:               # begin non-capture group
  [\t ]+          # match one or more tabs or spaces
  [^\s\d]+        # match one or more chars other than whitespaces or digits
)                 # end non-capture group
{0,6}             # execute non-capture group 0-6 times
[\t ]+            # match one or more tabs or spaces
(                 # begin capture group 2
  ...             # same tokens as those defining capture group 1
)                 # end capture group 2
/
```

Comment: Readers: I assumed I could define capture group 2 as `(\g{1})`, where `\g{1}` executes the tokens that define capture group 1 but [that does not work](https://rubular.com/r/ToxxNSwLLCPoaK). It [does work with with PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/4AS3Wb/1), however. Search "Subexpression Calls" [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/Regexp.html) for Ruby's documentation of `\g`. Any idea why `\g` doesn't work as I expected?

Comment: `\g` requires named captures, so you'd need to use capture groups like `(?<foo>\p{Alpha}{3})\g<foo>` rather than numerics or non-capturing groups. I also found it difficult to specify repeating patterns this way such as `(?<foo>\p{Alpha}{3})(?:\g<foo>){0,5}`, and while I imagine there's a way to do it--the above might even work given the right input--I wasn't invested enough in named captures as a solution to solve that particular problem tonight. :) Hope that helps!

Comment: @Todd, the Ruby doc link I gave states, "The `\g<name>` syntax matches the previous subexpression named name, which can be a group name **or number**, again.". Consider `"abcdef".match /\A(?<foo>\p{Alpha}{3})\g<foo>\z/ #=> #<MatchData "abcdef" foo:"def">` and `"abcdef".match /\A(\p{Alpha}{3})\g<1>\z/ #=> #<MatchData "abcdef" 1:"def">`, which are what I would expect...

Comment: ...Now consider `"abcdef".match /\A(?<foo>\p{Alpha}{3})(?<baz>\g<foo>)\z/ #=> #<MatchData "abcdef" foo:"def", baz:"def">` and `"abcdef".match /\A(\p{Alpha}{3})(\g<1>)\z/ #=> #<MatchData "abcdef" 1:"def" 2:"def">`. I was expecting these to return #<MatchData "abcdef" foo:"abc", baz:"def">` and `#<MatchData "abcdef" 1:"abc" 2:"def">`, respectively. That's what I got using PCRE.

Comment: You might be right about what it says. I'm just saying I can't get it to work half the time either. :)

Comment: @Todd, in my penultimate comment I meant I expected the two expressions to have returned `<MatchData "abcdef" foo:"abc">` and `#<MatchData "abcdef" 1:"abc">` (not `...foo:"def">` and `...1:"def">`), respectively.

Comment: @Stefan, can you answer my question?